# async_read() Boost::Asio C++

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, asio

Здравствуйте. Нужно принять строку от клиента через tcp соединение. 
Пример строки в 16 формате:

> 00 08 80 00 00 80 CD CD

Рабочий метод:

```
char buffer[10];
async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(buffer, 8)
        , [](boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_xfer){});
```

Но проблема в том, что размер пакета всегда разный. Поэтому это не подходит.

Пробовал вот так:

```
streambuf buf;
    async_read(socket_, buf
    , [](
      boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_xfer){});
```

Получаю исключение в файле *basic_streambuf.hpp*

```
void commit(std::size_t n)
  {
    if (pptr() + n > epptr()) //тут
      n = epptr() - pptr();
    pbump(static_cast<int>(n));
    setg(eback(), gptr(), pptr());
  }
```

> Exception thrown at 0x66D067FD (msvcp140d.dll) in TOPEmulator.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Еще пробовал сначала считать длину(получилось), а потом оставшуюся часть пакета, но там считываются другие значения.

```
      class TCPSession
        {
        ...
        private:
            std::unique_ptr<char> receive_buffer_;
        }
        void TCPSession::read_packet_len()
        {

            receive_buffer_.reset(new char[2]());
            async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(receive_buffer_.get(), 2)
                , [my = shared_from_this()](
                  boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_xfer){
                my->read_packet();
            });
        }

        void TCPSession::read_packet()
        {

            uShort datalen = 0;
            memcpy((char*)&datalen, receive_buffer_.get(), 2);
            boost::endian::endian_reverse_inplace<uShort>(datalen);
            std::cout << "datalen: " << datalen << endl; // результат 8
            receive_buffer_.reset(new char[datalen -2]());
                async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(receive_buffer_.get(), datalen - 2), 
    [my=shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_xfer)
       {/*проверяю считанные символы*/});
        }
```

Если использовать библиотеку "POCO", то все работает.

```
receiveBytes();
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно использовать вторую перегрузку функции `async_read` -  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload2.html.

В качестве `CompletionCondition` использовать `transfer_exactly`.

Получится что-то вроде:

```
size_t need_to_read_bytes = 8;
auto condition = boost::asio::transfer_exactly(need_to_read_bytes); 
async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(receive_buffer_.get(), datalen - 2), condition, 
    [my=shared_from_this()](boost::system::error_code const & error, size_t bytes_xfer)
    {
        /*проверяю считанные символы*/
    });
```